# Progressive Enhancement and Initial Display State

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-enhancement

I have a specific example, but I'm looking for the answer in general as well.  I have page elements that I want to have initially hidden if JavaScript is enabled.

Examples:

1. A section of a form that toggles
2. A submit button for a select box 'jump form'

I am trying to avoid the 'content flash' when the elements are hidden after page load.

---

**SOLUTION**

I am putting the full solution here for posterity's sake.

JavaScript file called in `<head>` section: `document.documentElement.className = 'js';`

Styles that allow for initially hidden or shown elements:

```
.js .inithide {
    display: none;
}
.initshow {
    display: none;
}
.js .initshow {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution out. It has worked for me in the past:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content

Comment: I'm gonna' try it!  I especially like the final solution, allowing for JS at the bottom.

Comment: Worked brilliantly!  Thanks again!